# MongoError: failed to connect to server in Node-RED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-red

I have a MongoDB running on http://linktomymongo:27017/. 
When I access this link via a browser I get the 
**"It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."** message.

However, when trying to access it through Node-RED I get some errors

Host: linktomymongo  Port: 27017
Error:

```
"MongoError: failed to connect to server [linktomymongo:27017] on first connect"
```

Host: http://linktomymongo Port: 27017
Error:

```
"Error: double colon in host identifier"
```

What am doing wrong? Any help is welcome.

If more information is required please ask :)

Node-RED mongo node (I have tried the link with and without `http://`: 
[image: Node-RED mongo config]

[image: editing database]

Comment: edit the question to add a screen shot of exactly what you have in the node-red config dialogue for the mongo node.

Comment: @hardillb see the updated questing. Was this wat you needed?

Comment: Can you ping to that url from a command window? According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206686/error-double-colon-in-host-identifer the problem might be a wrong url.

Comment: @derloopkat I am able to ping `linktomymongo`, I'd seen that question already but I don't think it is the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @derloopkat 's suggestion, I 'ping'ed `linktomymongo` and it showed the IP address. When I entered that IP address it connected immediately.

So I guess the node expects a IP address and not an URL

Comment: Or more likely you typo'd the hostname

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `http://`from the host section in the mongo node.

This is not a http connection it is a native mongo protocol connection.

Comment: I have tried that, but I get the following error: `MongoError: failed to connect to server [linktomymongo:27017] on first connect` (see question)